# Including constraints in objective function

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints

Apologies for the simple question. With $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, minimize $f(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb {R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

\begin{equation}\tag{*}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{min} \hspace{4mm} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x}  
\end{array}
\end{equation}

My approach: Any $\mathbf{x}^*$ that is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$ will make $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x}=0$. Since $\mathbf{x}$ is used later in my bigger problem, I want to get $\mathbf{x}^*$ that has minimum norm among all possible orthogonal vectors.

My question: How should I write the objective function with this minimum norm constraint. Secondly, since $\mathbf{0}$ is orthogonal to all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and it has a minimum norm, what should I do to avoid trivial solution i-e $\mathbf{x}^*\neq \mathbf{0}$.

First Edit:

How about reformulating in the following form

\begin{equation}\tag{**}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{min} \hspace{4mm} \|\mathbf{x}\|_2  \\
s.t. \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{v}=0 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Second Edit:

\begin{align*}\tag{***}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{min} \hspace{4mm} \|\mathbf{x}\|_2  \\
s.t. \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b} 
\end{array}
\end{align*}

where $\mathbf{e}\in \mathbb{R}^n$

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{e}= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}^T= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{v}^T \\ \mathbf{e}^T \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{b}= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: That looks fine with me.

Comment: @ Michael . . . thank you for your comment. My observation about $(**)$ is that I have not yet eliminated $\mathbf{0}$ in $(**)$. I can do this if I fix one element of $\mathbf{x}^*$ i-e $x_1=1$ and then formulate the Lagrangian with the equality constraint. Take a look at second edit that does this. Thank you once again

Comment: I'm really not sure what to say. Only you can say whether the model does what you want it to do, because only you know its application.